# Using if-statement and for-loop

Tags: r, for-loop, if-statement

I have a data frame, which looks like:

```
pr     class
0,317   1
0,579   3
0,317   1
0,426   2
9,851   7
0,992   3
3,731   5
1,909   4
0,426   2
9,851   7
3,731   5
9,851   7
```

I need to change probability if it is not equal to particular value in the particular class. For example, if the class is 1 and the probability is not 0.317, I need to change it to 0.317.

I tried to use for one class `for`-loop and `if`-statement but for some reason it didn't work at all.

```
for(class in data_frame) {
  if(data_frame$class = 1) {
    data_frame$pr = 0.317
  }
}
```

I tried only with one class because I don't have any idea how I can do it for all classes in one code (may be another `for`-loop?).

Comment: You would need `==`. A better option might be to create a lookup table containing the correct `pr` values for each `class` and then do a `merge`.

Comment: Should be `data_frame$class == 1` or try to use vector form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is the fastest way but it works.

```
class <- c(1,2,2,1,2,2)  
p <- c()
for (i in 1:length(class)){
if(class[i] == 1) p[i] = .01
if(class[i] == 2) p[i] = .02
}
as.data.frame(rbind(p,class))
```

From how I understand you, you don't need the original values in or at all, right? 
So just use a vector class which contains your classes and then an empty vector p which is going to hold your probabilities. Then run the loop. It's important to use == for if clauses instead of = as this assigns a value to an object. The last line returns the two vectors as one data frame

Comment: Thanks a lot! Now I got it :)

Answer (score 0):

Your `for` loop is probably not behaving as you expect:

```
for (class in data_frame) {
  print(class)
}
```

> ```
> >
>  [1] 0.317 0.579 0.317 0.426 9.851 0.992 3.731 1.909 0.426 9.851 3.731 9.851
>  [1] 1 3 1 2 7 3 5 4 2 7 5 7
> ```

This version might be what you intended. The `&&` checks whether the current row's value is 0.317 or not as well.

```
data_frame <- read.table("data.txt", header = TRUE)  # reads data

for (i in 1:nrow(data_frame)) {  # does one row at a time
  if (data_frame[i,]$class == 1  && data_frame[i,]$pr != 0.317) {  # replaces value in current row if TRUE and TRUE
    data_frame[i,]$pr <- 0.317
  }
}
```